# como editar archivo netCDF usando python? generar otro .nc solo con una parte del original?

Tags: python, netcdf4

soy nuevo con python y mas aun con netCDF. Mi situación es la siguiente...
Debo bajar los archivos .nc generados x el ASCAT (informacion del viento sobre el mar). Disponibles en ftp://podaac-ftp.jpl.nasa.gov/allData/ascat/preview/L2/metop_a/25km/  /año/dia

Usando la libreria NETCDF4 de python, que ya la tengo instalada y funcionando.. debo abrir el fichero descargado, y por así decirlo "recortarlo". tomando solo los datos comprendidos entre 0 a 90 grados de latitud sur.
0 a 140 grados de longitud oeste.

Entonces.. descargo el archivo, debería abrirlo y generar otro donde solo estén los datos de esta región... cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar para poder hacer esto, les voy a agradecer mucho!! saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Muestra el código y el error que obtienes. Aquí tienes la documentación de la biblioteca: http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/

Comment: Hola kiko, realmente solo tengo el código que lee los archivos. Me lista las longitudes y las latitudes. El tiempo, la velocidad, etc... Ahora eh probado con algunos if, pero es q realmente no se como hacer para acceder a ese valor q me lista. tampoco como copiar la informacion de esta parte q me interesa.  Desde ya, gracias! adjunto el codigo de lectura en el comentario sgts

Comment: este seria el codigo de lectura: <br/>  vars =  nc_file.variables.keys()
nvars = len(vars)
print 'Number of variables = ', nvars

for i in range(0, nvars):
        vardata = var_data_list[i]
        print '----------'
        print var_attr_list[i]
        print vars[i], '[0:10] =\n', vardata[0:10]

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y mete el código y toda la información útil en el cuerpo de la pregunta para que te puedan ayudar de la mejor forma posible. Tal como lo has pegado no es fácil de leer. Para meter código en la pregunta puedes usar el botón del editor cuyo símbolo es `{}`